# BrightCove Videos not playing on the Android/iOS devices

Tags: android, ios

I have issue in playing the Brightcove videos on the Android/iOS .
The same code which is working on the desktop is not working on the Mobile devices.

Has anyone idea  about this why this is happening ?

The code which i am using for the Test purpose found on this link-->
https://gist.github.com/bcls/7535049

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Smart Player API: Basic Setup</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Start of Brightcove Player -->

  <div style="display:none">
  </div>


  <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="http://admin.brightcove.com/js/BrightcoveExperiences.js"></script>

  <object id="myExperience922656010001" class="BrightcoveExperience">
   <param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF" />
   <param name="width" value="480" />
   <param name="height" value="270" />
   <param name="playerID" value="2344262015001" />
   <param name="playerKey" value="AQ~~,AAAA1oy1bvE~,ALl2ezBj3WHB4SZjVHPI3HSdWBlOCXX4" />
   <param name="isVid" value="true" />
   <param name="isUI" value="true" />
   <param name="dynamicStreaming" value="true" />

   <param name="@videoPlayer" value="922656010001" />

   <!-- smart player api params -->
   <param name="includeAPI" value="true" />
   <param name="templateLoadHandler" value="onTemplateLoad" />
   <param name="templateReadyHandler" value="onTemplateReady" />

  </object>

  <!--
    This script tag will cause the Brightcove Players defined above it to be created as soon
    as the line is read by the browser. If you wish to have the player instantiated only after
    the rest of the HTML is processed and the page load is complete, remove the line.
  -->
  <script type="text/javascript">brightcove.createExperiences();</script>

  <!-- End of Brightcove Player -->

  <script type="text/JavaScript">
    var player,
    APIModules,
    videoPlayer;

    function onTemplateLoad(experienceID){
     player = brightcove.api.getExperience(experienceID);
     APIModules = brightcove.api.modules.APIModules;
    }

    function onTemplateReady(evt){
     videoPlayer = player.getModule(APIModules.VIDEO_PLAYER);
     videoPlayer.play();
    }
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order to help others understand your issue, please post a sample of code, outputs of any logs (e.g. LogCat) or something to demonstrate a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

it isn't possible to auto fire event like play or fullscreen in mobile devices, because these events need customer interaction. The code is right but due to a technical property of the player the event can't fire.

At the link below you can find a list of Known Issues about BC, like video playback on mobile devices.

[Brightcove Known Issues](https://support.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/docs/known-issues#smartplayerapi)

I hope it could be useful

Comment: Thanks for reply. Actually problem exist only on the Android devices , on iPad/iPhone it's fine. It was my mistake to mention the iOS devices.Problem exist only on the Android devices.When i try to play on the Android devices white screen comes and nothing.

Answer (score 0):

It's late reply but there was issue in my project setting when i tried to run that as standalone. It was working. So if this problem happens in you project, try running it in standalone project.